# Link to .php file inside action=" " in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, database, forms, wordpress

```
<?php
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $pupils_table ORDER BY surname ASC");
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
?>

<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='/pupil/?pupil=<?php echo $print->id;?>'">
    <td><?php echo $print->firstname;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->surname;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->gender;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->dob;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->startdate;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->eal;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->send;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->pp;?></td>
    <td>
        <form action='<?php plugins_url(); ?>/foundtrack/includes/delete-pupil.php?id="<?php echo $print->id;?>"' method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $print->id;?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
        </form>
    </td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

How would I link to my delete-pupil.php file inside of a form within a wordpress plugin. I've tried lots of different things and none have worked. It would be a lot easier if this was just php without wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in WordPress, you do not post directly to a form processor in your plugins directory. Instead, you would "listen" for the form submission and process it within WordPress.

```
add_action('init', 'foundtrack_form_processor');
function foundtrack_form_processor() {
    if(!empty($_POST['some_unique_form_var_name'])) {
        return;
    }
    //do form processing here
}
```

Doing it this way enables you to have access to all of the WordPress functionality without having to manually load WordPress in your form processor.

You would just leave your action blank in this case.

Comment: how would I incorporate this into my problem?

Comment: You would just need to add that code to your plugin. It's hard to say specifically how you would incorporate it into your plugin without knowing more.

Comment: Ok I understand. How would I link this with action="" inside of the form?

Comment: You could just leave it blank, which would just post to the current page.